# Maven deploy multi module project only if all modules build successfully

Tags: maven, artifactory

I have a maven multi module project with several modules. I want to deploy them (`mvn deploy`) only if they all pass a full `mvn install` (which includes the tests).

Currently, I run a `mvn install` on the project. If all modules pass, I run `mvn deploy` to do the deployment. The problem I see is the waste of time calling `mvn` twice (even if I skip tests on the second run).

Does anyone have an idea on this?

---

**EDIT:** I have learned that using [Artifactory](https://www.jfrog.com/artifactory/) as a repository manager and the [maven-artifactory-plugin](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Maven+Artifactory+Plugin) with your maven setup will add the **atomic deploy** behaviour to the `mvn deploy` command. See the [Build Integration](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Build+Integration) section in the Artifactory documentation.

[DISCLOSURE - I'm associated with JFrog. Artifactory creator.]

Comment: Have you tried to use **mvn deploy:deploy** instead ?

Comment: This will still require me to call mvn twice. I want a one shot solution (if exists)

Comment: See this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18192686/maven-multi-module-deploy-to-repository-only-after-successful-unit-tests

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at the `deployAtEnd` parameter of Maven Deployment plugin: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/deploy-mojo.html

Comment: I tried it (mvn deploy -DdeployAtEnd=true) and it didn't make a difference. Does it require a special configuration? I use maven 3.0.4...

Comment: that option was added in 2.8 of the deploy plugin, maybe you use an older version?

Answer (score 3):

This is a bit tricky. Maven is not atomic when it executes the build life-cycle. So a broken set of artifacts may end up in a repository.

One solution I know is Nexus Pro: http://www.sonatype.com/Products/Nexus-Professional/Features  - it allows you to promote builds or define certain repos as staging. So only verified versions get promoted to be used. Maybe artifactory has something similar - I just don't know.

If that solution is too expensive you probably need to create a cleanup build or profile to remove artifacts that where already uploaded. My first guess would be to write a Maven plugin to use the the proxy remote API or maybe the maven features are already sufficient. But since deploy means update the meta-data xml files too I dont think there is a delete - not sure on this either.